# How do I hide this menu with a media query in ReactJS/NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am having issues getting my hamburger menu to hide when the screen size gets to a certain width. If I do not manually close the hamburger menu before changing the screen size the hamburger menu goes away but the menu icons stay in place and a duplicate menu is observed.

Here is my Navbar component:

```
// Navbar component.
export default function Navbar() {
    // to change burger classes
    const [burger_class, setBurgerClass] = useState("burger-bar unclicked")
    const [isMenuClicked, setIsMenuClicked] = useState(false)
    const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false);

    // toggle burger menu change
    const updateMenu = () => {
      if(!isMenuClicked) {
          setBurgerClass("burger-bar clicked")
          setIsMenuVisible(true)
          
      }
      else {
          setBurgerClass("burger-bar unclicked")
          setIsMenuVisible(false)
      }
      setIsMenuClicked(!isMenuClicked)
  }
  return (
  <>
    <nav id="nav" className="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <span id="site-title" className="navbar-brand">
          Large Gate Studios
        </span>
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <div className="burger-menu" onClick={updateMenu}>
            <div className={burger_class} ></div>
            <div className={burger_class} ></div>
            <div className={burger_class} ></div>
          </div>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/team">Our Team</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <li className="nav-item" style={{'display':` ${isMenuVisible ? 'inline' : 'none'}`}}>
        <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item" style={{'display':` ${isMenuVisible ? 'inline' : 'none'}`}}>
          <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/team">Our Team</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item" style={{'display':` ${isMenuVisible ? 'inline' : 'none'}`}}>
          <Link id="a" className="nav" href="/contact">Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </>
  );
}
```

Here is the CSS for this class:

```
#nav {
  background-color: #e2e1e1;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

#logo-img {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#site-title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
  
#a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
  
#a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.burger-bar:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#link {
  display: inline;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#link:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .burger-menu {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .burger-bar {
    display: inline;
    width: 3em;
    height: 0.5em;
    background-color: #292f36;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    margin: 2px;
  }

  .nav-item {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width >= 1200px) {
  .burger-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .burger-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

How can I fix my hamburger menu so that it closes as expected when the screen size increase according to my media query?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with the hamburger menu not closing as expected when the screen size increases, you can make the following modifications to your code:

1. Remove the duplicate menu items: In your current code, you have duplicate menu items outside the  element. Remove the duplicate

   elements with the inline styles that display the menu items based on the isMenuVisible state.
2. Add an event listener for window resize: Use the useEffect hook to add an event listener for the window resize event. In the event listener, check if the screen size is larger than the defined breakpoint, and if so, set isMenuVisible and isMenuClicked to false to close the hamburger menu.

Here's the updated code for the Navbar component:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    export default function Navbar() {
  

    const [burgerClass, setBurgerClass] = useState("burger-bar unclicked");
      const [isMenuClicked, setIsMenuClicked] = useState(false);
      const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false);

  const updateMenu = () => {
    if (!isMenuClicked) {
      setBurgerClass("burger-bar clicked");
      setIsMenuVisible(true);
    } else {
      setBurgerClass("burger-bar unclicked");
      setIsMenuVisible(false);
    }
    setIsMenuClicked(!isMenuClicked);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
        setIsMenuClicked(false);
        setIsMenuVisible(false);
        setBurgerClass("burger-bar unclicked");
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <nav id="nav" className="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <span id="site-title" className="navbar-brand">
            Large Gate Studios
          </span>
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <div className="burger-menu" onClick={updateMenu}>
              <div className={burgerClass}></div>
              <div className={burgerClass}></div>
              <div className={burgerClass}></div>
            </div>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a id="a" className="nav" href="/">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a id="a" className="nav" href="/team">
                Our Team
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a id="a" className="nav" href="/contact">
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I remove the extra menu it does not work but when I leave the extra menu in place and just add the event listener it works as expected.